# Error C2100 - Illegal Indirection

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, compiler-errors

I have a very simple program written to define a * operator in an array template class.
When I try to compile it gives me an error "illegal indirection".
Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

This is the operator definition:

```
template <typename T>                                                                   
NumericArray<T> NumericArray<T>::operator * (const int factor) const
{
NumericArray<T>* TempArray2 = new NumericArray<T>(Size());
for (int i=0; i<Size(); i++)
{
    *TempArray2[i] = ((GetElement(i))*(factor));
}
return *TempArray2;
}
```

And this is the implementation in the test main function:

```
cout<<((*intArray1)*5).GetElement(0);                                   
cout<<((*intArray1)*5).GetElement(1);
cout<<((*intArray1)*5).GetElement(2);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't forget your [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) rules. It seems that you want:

```
(*TempArray2)[i]
```

Otherwise your expression `*TempArray2[i]` is considered as `*(TempArray2[i])` and I suppose your `NumericArray<T>` type doesn't have the *unary* `*` operator overloaded.

Answer (score 2):

In `*TempArray2[i]`, the `*` is applied to `TempArray[2]` because of the precedence rules, and there's a fair chance that the array elements don't have a unary `*` operator.

*But* your use of dynamic allocation and then dereferencing to return by value means that you have a memory leak.
(You don't need `new` to create objects in C++ - you probably don't need to use it in `main` either.)

This would be better (and avoids the whole indirection issue):

```
template <typename T>                                                                   
NumericArray<T> NumericArray<T>::operator * (int factor) const
{
    NumericArray<T> TempArray(Size());
    for (int i = 0; i < Size(); i++)
    {
        TempArray[i] = GetElement(i) * factor;
    }
    return TempArray;
}
```